# How do I filter data in a ForeignKey Django to display the corresponding data?

Tags: python, html, django, view

```
class Entrepreneur(models.Model)
f
...

Class Skills(models.Model) 
usevalue = models.ForeignKey(Entrepreneur)
rating = (rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),MaxValueValidator(5)])
```

Hello I am on a professional project and I had a question given that I am a young developer for the moment I did not know how to filter the data of the skills model for the entrepreneur and that I can filter it and then I can display it on the frontend. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for skills for a specific Entrepreneur using there pk, you you can link tables together easily in Django

```py
skills = Skills.objects.filter(usevalue__id="your entrepreneur id value")
```

Or if you are searching for an entrepreneur for a specific for a rating of skill

```py
entrepreneurs = Entrepreneur.objects.filter(skills__rating="skill rating value")
```

Also note you should have an on_delete parameter on your foreign key

Comment: So ,                                                                                                                                                                            def get(request , entrepreneur_pk )                                                                                                                                                                               entrepreneur = get_object_or_404(Entrepreneur, id=entrepreneur_pk)                                                     
skills = Skills.objects.filter (usevalue__id=  entrepreneur) That's good like that ?

Comment: Play around and try it out (normally the error messages are useful), check the Django docs for more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships